# How to implement reduced-rank regression in R?

Tags: r, reduced-rank-regression

How can I fit reduced-rank regression with continuous response in R?

I found the package `VGAM` but it only fits for discrete distributions...

Comment: I do not know R, but reduced-rank regression has an explicit solution via standard regression and SVD, so it should not be difficult to implement manually.

Comment: I'd be surprised is VGAM didn't do this; it has plenty of continuous distribution family functions (though note I haven't looked in detail at the RRR function in VGAM recently). You can also do something that is known as reduced rank regression with the **vegan** package. We call this Redundancy Analysis (RDA) but it also goes by the name reduced rank regression. And as @amoeba says, RDA can be computed by doing `fit <- fitted(lm(Y ~ X, data = foo))` then `prcomp(fit)`. If this is what you want, then `rda()` in **vegan** would be a good start.

Comment: @amoeba we may be talking about slightly different methods - RDA gets called a lot of things. We implement it in `rda()` via QR decomposition and SVD for efficiency, but *that* method gets the same result as the R code I showed in the comment earlier. Which makes me think what we do, which has been called reduced rank regression, is not the reduced rank regression the OP is looking for :-)

Comment: Thank you all, I'll try to use this. I'm still trying to understand the rank reduced model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set of S functions for least-squares reduced-rank can be found in the [StatLib](http://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/math/statlib/S/) archive.
See the file [rrr.s](http://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/math/statlib/S/rrr.s) and this [paper](http://www.nr.no/~aldrin/artikler/RRR.EncEnvironmetrics.2002.pdf):

> Splus function for reduced-rank regression and softly shrunk
>   reduced-rank regression. Submitted by Magne Aldrin
>   (magne.aldrin@nr.no). [19/Apr/99][8/Mar/00] (14k)

Answer (score 2):

There are now R packages for reduced-rank regression: [rrpack](https://rdrr.io/cran/rrpack/), [rrr](https://rdrr.io/cran/rrr/).